# how to stop serialization of subclass?

Tags: java, serialization

How to stop serialization of subclass if superclass is implementing `Serializable` interface?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [writeObject()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/output.html#861) method to achieve this.

You can use `writeObject` customize the serialization behaviour of an object, if you don't wat to allow serialization of an `Class` you override this method and throw an error.

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream stream)
        throws IOException {
    throw new IOException('No serialization not allowed')
}
```

Comment: perfect answer!

Answer (score 6):

Implement `readObject` and `writeObject` methods to unconditionally throw an `IOException`.  Ugly but effective.

Unfortunately, you cannot stop a sub-subclass from implementing its own `readObject` and `writeObject` methods to restore "serializability" ... unless you declare the subclass as `final`.

Of course, this is questionable OO design (it violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)), but if you really need to do it ...

Comment: +1 for mentioning Liskov Substitution Principle

Answer (score -1):

Make all properties transient :)

Comment: Class still be serializable

Comment: What would you do serializing a class anyway when none of its properties can be persisted?

Comment: What is about parent's properties?

Comment: My bad, ignored that fact.